# How can I create CI/CD pipeline with cloudbuild.yaml in GCP?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-build, gitops

I am trying to create a simple CI/CD pipeline. After the client makes `git push`, it will start a trigger with the below `cloudbuilder.yaml`:

```sh
# steps:
# - name: 'docker/compose:1.28.2'
#   args: ['up', '-d']
# - name: "docker/compose:1.28.2"
#   args: ["build"]
# images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose']
# - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
#   id: 'backend'
#   args: ['build','-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest','.']
# - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
#   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest']

# steps:
# - name: 'docker/compose:1.28.2'
#   args: ['up', '-d']
# - name: "docker/compose:1.28.2"
#   args: ["build"]
# images:
# - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose'

# In this directory, run the following command to build this builder.
# $ gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml
substitutions:
  _DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.28.2
steps:
- name: 'docker/compose:1.28.2'
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '--build-arg'
  - 'DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=${_DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}'
  - '-t'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest'
  - '-t'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:${_DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}'
  - '.'
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose'
  args: ['version']

images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:${_DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}'
tags: ['cloud-builders-community']
```

It returns the error below: it cannot create images in the repository. How can I solve this issue?

````sh
ERROR: failed to pull because we ran out of retries.
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/internal-invoicing-solution/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose" failed: error pulling build step 1 "gcr.io/internal-invoicing-solution/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose": generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (10 attempts): step exited with non-zero status: 1
```
````

Comment: Did you try following one of the [GCP-provided quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd) for building a CI/CD pipeline? Does the error reproduce while using these samples?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer : yes below code is problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before pulling your image in the 2nd step, you need to push it. When you declare the `images` at the end of your yaml definition, the image are pushed automatically at the end on the pipeline. Here you need it in the middle.

---

**EDIT 1**

I just added a docker push step, copy and paste from your comments. Does it work?

```
substitutions:
  _DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.28.2
steps:
- name: 'docker/compose:1.28.2'
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '--build-arg'
  - 'DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=${_DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}'
  - '-t'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest'
  - '-t'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:${_DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}'
  - '.'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest']
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose'
  args: ['version']

images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:latest'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-demo-dockercompose:${_DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}'
tags: ['cloud-builders-community']
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample because I took all solutions on the internet but they are not working? I am not trying to get ready for things. Pease help me for that :(

Comment: I edited my answer with a proposition. Does it work?